# Search and filter pandas dataframe with regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'd appreciate your help. I have a pandas dataframe. I want to search 3 columns of the dataframe using a regular expression, then return all rows that meet the search criteria, sorted by one of my columns. I would like to write this as a function so I can implement this logic with other criteria if possible, but am not quite sure how to do this.

For example, I know how pull the results of a search thusly (with col1 being a column name):

```
idx1 = df.col1.str.contains(r'vhigh|high', flags=re.IGNORECASE, regex=True, na=False)

print df[~idx1]
```

but I can't figure out how to take this type of action, and perform it with multiple columns and then sort. Anyone have any tips?

Comment: how about doing what you've shown above but iterating over each column.  then just store the resulting indexes as sets; finally you can just find the intersection of the sets for your final desired rows.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `apply` to make the code more concise. For example, given this DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'col1': ['vhigh', 'low', 'vlow'],
        'col2': ['eee', 'low', 'high'],
        'val': [100,200,300]
    }
)
print df
```

Input:

```
    col1  col2  val
0  vhigh   eee  100
1    low   low  200
2   vlow  high  300
```

You can select all the rows that contain the strings `vhigh` or `high` in columns `col1` or `col2` as follow:

```
mask = df[['col1', 'col2']].apply(
    lambda x: x.str.contains(
        'vhigh|high',
        regex=True
    )
).any(axis=1)
print df[mask]
```

The `apply` function applies the `contains` function on each column (since by default `axis=0`). The `any` function returns a Boolean mask, with element True indicating that at least one of the columns met the search criteria. This can then be used to perform selection on the original DataFrame.

Output:

```
    col1  col2  val
0  vhigh   eee  100
2   vlow  high  300
```

Then, to sort the result by a column, e.g. the `val` column, you could simply do:

```
df[mask].sort('val')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm not very familiar with lambda functions so this is really useful. Could you point me to something that would explain a bit more the syntax of the last command: `df[mask]` I'm not familiar with that use of brackets.

Comment: That particular use of brackets is called [Boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing). The same page contains information about other ways of indexing and selecting data, which is worth a read.

Comment: Attempt at explaining: `mask` is a new series created which is holding a True/False value for every row in df. `df[mask]` results in filtering the rows and showing only those rows that are True as per the mask column. Typically we assign these to a new column in the same df itself. And I think the `.sort('val')` is now deprecated.. do `df[mask].sort_values('val')` instead.